# Is a custom JSF converter needed for this simple class?

Tags: java, jsf

I have been trying with limited success to code a JSF application. In one section of the application, I need users to select from a select menu which displays a list of selectable status values. The Status class (presented below), which is used to populate the List that is displayed in the select menu, is a simple class made up of two Strings: one is the code used to look up the description in the database, the other is the human-readable description. I am trying to find out if I need a converter here at all, and if so, how best to implement the converter. This is a JSF 1.1 project using Java 1.5

I am using the following code in the JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
 <f:view>
<html>
<h:graphicImage id="image" url="/images/appname.jpg"
    alt="app name" />
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<jsp:include page="/jsp/menu.jsp" />
</head>
<body>

<h:outputText
    value="Add Value"
    style="font-size:20px;" />

<h:messages errorStyle="color: red" infoStyle="color: green"
    layout="table" />

<h:form id="statusReasonEditForm">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><h:outputText id="txtvalue" value="Status" /></td>
            <td><h:selectOneMenu id="selectStatus"
                value="#{pc_statusReasonBacker.status}"
                binding="#{pc_statusReasonBacker.selectItem}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{pc_statusReasonBacker.selectStatuses}" />
                <f:converter converterId="statusConverter" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <td><h:outputText id="txtvaluereason" value="Status Reason" /></td>
            <td><h:inputText id="txtinputreason"
                value="#{pc_statusReasonBacker.statusReason.statusReason}"
                maxlength="100" size="40" /></td>
            <td><h:outputText id="txtvaluereasondesc"
                value="Status Reason Desc" /></td>
            <td><h:inputText id="txtinputreasondesc"
                value="#{pc_statusReasonBacker.statusReason.statusReasonDesc}"
                maxlength="100" size="40" /></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <tr>
        <td><h:commandButton id="savebutton" value="Save"
            action="#{pc_statusReasonBacker.save}" /></td>
        <td><h:commandButton id="cancelbutton" value="Cancel"
            action="#{pc_statusReasonBacker.cancel}" /></td>
    </tr>

</h:form>
<hr />
</body>
</html>
 </f:view>
```

The backing bean is shown here (some non-related sections, such as paging, removed for clarity):

public class StatusReasonBacker {

```
private List<StatusReason> statusReasonList;
private List<Status> statusList;
private List<SelectItem> selectStatuses;
private StatusReason statusReason;
private StatusDao sDao;
private Status status;
private UIData statusReasonTable;
private HtmlSelectOneMenu selectItem;
private String selectedStatus = "";

public StatusReasonBacker() {
    sDao = new StatusDao();
    statusReason = new StatusReason();
    selectStatuses = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    status = new Status();
    selectItem = new HtmlSelectOneMenu();
}

public String insert() {
    status.setStatusCde("");
    statusReason.setStatus(status);
    statusReason.setStatusReason("");
    statusReason.setStatusReasonCde("");
    statusReason.setStatusReasonDesc("");
    return "success";
}

public String edit() {
    this.statusReason = (StatusReason) statusReasonTable.getRowData();
    selectItem.setValue(statusReason.getStatus().getStatusCde());
    return "success";
}

public String update() {

    if ("".equalsIgnoreCase(statusReason.getStatusReason().trim())) {
        Message
                .addErrorMessage("You must enter a value for the status reason.");
        return "failure";
    } else if (("".equalsIgnoreCase(statusReason.getStatusReasonDesc()
            .trim()))) {
        Message
                .addErrorMessage("You must enter a value for the status reason description.");
        return "failure";
    }
    sDao.updateStatusReason(statusReason);

    return "statusreasons";
}

public String delete() {
    StatusReason statReason = (StatusReason) statusReasonTable.getRowData();
    sDao.deleteStatusReason(statReason);
    return "statusreasons";
}

public String cancel() {
    return "statusreasons";
}

public String save() {

    statusReason.setStatus(status);
    sDao.insertStatusReason(statusReason);
    return "statusreasons";
}

...

public StatusDao getSDao() {
    return sDao;
}

public void setSDao(StatusDao dao) {
    sDao = dao;
}

public List<StatusReason> getStatusReasonList() {
    statusReasonList = sDao.getStatusReasons();
    return statusReasonList;
}

public void setStatusReasonList(List<StatusReason> statusReasonList) {
    this.statusReasonList = statusReasonList;
}

public UIData getStatusReasonTable() {
    return statusReasonTable;
}

public void setStatusReasonTable(UIData statusReasonTable) {
    this.statusReasonTable = statusReasonTable;
}

public StatusReason getStatusReason() {
    return statusReason;
}

public void setStatusReason(StatusReason statusReason) {
    this.statusReason = statusReason;
}

public List<Status> getStatusList() {
    statusList = sDao.getStatuses();
    return statusList;
}

public void setStatusList(List<Status> statusList) {
    this.statusList = statusList;
}

public List<SelectItem> getSelectStatuses() {

    selectStatuses.clear();
    if (statusList == null) {
        statusList = this.getStatusList();
    }

    for (Status sr : statusList) {

        SelectItem si = new SelectItem();
        si.setValue(sr.getStatusCde());
        si.setLabel(sr.toString());
        si.setDescription(sr.toString());
        selectStatuses.add(si);
    }
    return selectStatuses;
}

public void setSelectStatuses(List<SelectItem> selectStatuses) {
    this.selectStatuses = selectStatuses;
}

public String getSelectedStatus() {
    selectedStatus = statusReason.getStatusDesc();
    return selectedStatus;
}

public void setSelectedStatus(String selectedStatus) {
    this.selectedStatus = selectedStatus;
}

public Status getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(Status status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public HtmlSelectOneMenu getSelectItem() {
    return selectItem;
}

public void setSelectItem(HtmlSelectOneMenu selectItem) {
    this.selectItem = selectItem;
}

 }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *I am trying to find out if I need a converter here at all, and if so, how best to implement the converter.*

You need a converter whenever you want to pass non-standard Java Objects from a HTTP request to another HTTP request. With non-standard I mean *not* a [`String`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), [`Number`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) or [`Boolean`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html). This all simply because HTTP request parameters can **only** be `Strings`. That `Number` and `Boolean` works is because [EL](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) can recognize them and has built-in coercions for it.

For non-standard Java Objects you need to implement a [`javax.faces.convert.Converter`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html) which converts the Object to a `String` (or a `Number` so you want, for example a `Long id` which can be the PK of the associated row in database table) inside the `getAsString()` method before displaying in HTML. You do the other way round in the `getAsObject()` method during processing of the request parameters (e.g. get the associated object from DAO by its `id`).

You can find [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/09/objects-in-hselectonemenu.html) an example of how to use a `Converter` for a `h:selectOneMenu`. You see that this article also contains an alternative, but you'll need to do a bit more work in the backing bean to convert (map) the objects yourself.